# Should a question on installation of the Delphi IDE have been migrated from SO to Super User?

Tags: discussion

This question was just migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User: [How do I fix a Delphi installation when "repair" doesn't work?](https://superuser.com/questions/526528)

I know that it concerns installation, but it seems to me to require specific knowledge and expertise that will be much more readily found on Stack Overflow than on Super User. Does that matter? Is the fact that it concerns installation of a product enough to mean that its home is on Super User?

I ask the question so that I will know in future what to do. If the correct home is on Super User then I'll stop answering the questions on SO and then vote to migrate them.

Comment: The migration *to SU* is no problem: It's perfectly on topic on SU. Whether the migration *away from SO* was appropriate is probably best asked on MSO. There is some topic overlap between Stack Exchange sites (e.g. we accept Ubuntu questions even though there is Ask Ubuntu), so the question being on topic on SU does not mean it's off topic on SO. FWIW, I'd consider it on topic for SO, as it's about *software tools commonly used by programmers*.

Comment: What @DanielBeck says makes definitely sense. However, in this case SO should _keep_ the question as it's not just an "installation issue". Repairing some components may be solved by small hacks, which the users of SO would possibly know better.

Comment: We rarely if ever have issues with the content of migrated votes IMO, its more often *quality* that gets people riled up, the question looks fine to me.